# Columns not changing colours - Bootstrap issue?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Im trying to change the colours of the column names but it stays white.
Look:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <button id="exportButton" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover custom-table">
        <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr>
                    <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                    <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                    <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                    <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                    <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                    <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                    <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                    <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                    <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                    <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                    <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                </tr>
```

i added: **custom-table** and then, i applied an style:

```
.custom-table {
    background-color: rgb(249, 159, 25);
}
```

Colour is not applied. Why?

Tried without success

---

EDIT #1:
This is my full code, take a look:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="TAB2" role="tabpanel">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <button id="exportButton" class="btn btn-primary">bUTTON</button>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-hover custom-table">
            <thead class="thead-light">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                        <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                        <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                        <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                        <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                        <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                        <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                        <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                        <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                        <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                        <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                    </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {% for dato in datos_#1 %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ dato.#1 }}</td>
                        <td>{{ dato.#1}}</td>
                        <td class="text-truncate">{{ dato.#1}}</td>
                        <td>{{ dato.#1}}</td>
                        <td>{{ dato.#1}}</td>
                        <td class="text-truncate">{{ dato.#1}}</td>
                        <td>{{ dato.#1}}</td>
                        <td class="text-truncate"><a href="{{ dato.#1}}" target="_blank">ME</a></td>
                        <td class="text-truncate">{{ dato.#1}}</td>
                        <td>{{ dato.#1}}</td>
                        <td class="text-truncate"><a href="{{ dato.#1}}" target="_blank">mE</a></td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

i dont know why but its not working for me :/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Hey @Paulie_D. Take a look, i edited my question

Answer (score -1):

What you are essentially doing is applying background color to the table. In order to see the background color, make sure you properly close the table tag and perhaps fill some data.

```
 <div class="table-responsive">
  <button id="exportButton" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover custom-table">
      <thead class="thead-light">
              <tr>
                  <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                  <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                  <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                  <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                  <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                  <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                  <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                  <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                  <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                  <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
                  <th class="text-truncate">#1</th>
              </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <td>This is a test.</td>
      </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey pal. 
Look, i edited my question. Its not what you saying :(

Comment: If you mean that you are not able to see anything, then prob you should remove the class fade from the first div.

Comment: No, not working pal

Comment: Which version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>